# How to save uploaded file

Tags: java, vaadin, eclipse-mars, vaadin8

I would like to know how to get a file from a Vaadin Upload Component. Here is the example on the [Vaadin Website](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-upload.html)
but it does not include how to save it other than something about OutputStreams.
Help!

Comment: As said in docs, you have a method called `receiveUpload`. In this method, you take a filename and its mime type. Then you must create an `OutputStream`[(java 7 doc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html)  with a `File` with that filename and return it... Of course, the `File` must be located where you want to save the upload.

Comment: @Shirkam Can I have some code? as location being C:\

Comment: Yeah why not, stackoverflow is your cost-free programmer community...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To receive a file upload in Vaadin, you must implement `Receiver` interface, wich provides you with a `receiveUpload(filename, mimeType)`method, used to receive the info. The simplest code to do this would be (Taken as example from  [Vaadin 7 docs](https://vaadin.com/docs7/-/part7/framework/components/components-upload.html)):

```
class FileUploader implements Receiver {
    private File file;
    private String BASE_PATH="C:\\";

    public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename,
                                  String mimeType) {
        // Create upload stream
        FileOutputStream fos = null; // Stream to write to
        try {
            // Open the file for writing.
            file = new File(BASE_PATH + filename);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (final java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            new Notification("Could not open file<br/>",
                         e.getMessage(),
                         Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE)
            .show(Page.getCurrent());
            return null;
        }
        return fos; // Return the output stream to write to
    }
};
```

With that, the `Uploader` will write you a file in `C:\`. If you wish to something after the upload has completed successfully, or not, you can implement `SucceeddedListener` or `FailedListener`. Taking the example above, the result (with a `SucceededListener`) could be:

```
class FileUploader implements Receiver {
    //receiveUpload implementation

    public void uploadSucceeded(SucceededEvent event) {
        //Do some cool stuff here with the file
    }
}
```